# Saving organization-wide application settings in Teams app

Tags: microsoft-teams

I have a Teams application (Tab). I am an ISV provider, and provide a multi-tenant application that is installed by customers via Teams App Store in their organizations.

How do I save settings for my application organization-wide for the customers? For example, CustomerA has installed the app and then CustomerB. I want some storage that would be unique for CustomerA and CustomerB and the app, and **located in customer's environment**. The settings I want to save are not per-user, but **per-organization** (tenant).

Somewhat similar to "App Data" folder you have in Windows Desktop for example.

Does such a storage exist? Does API for this storage exist?

Comment: As said by Hilton, it is totally up to you to handle. You can also store the info as [SameSite cookie](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/samesite-cookie-update#samesite-cookie-attribute-2020-release). I can't remember that there is sych API or storage available.

Answer (score 1):

A tab app is a simply a web application that you render inside of Teams. As a result, what the app does, and where and how it does it, is totally up to you. This includes any data storage you choose to have behind the scenes. For example, your tab could be built in PHP and use MySQL, or built in ASP.Net and use SQL Azure or CosmosDB. It's totally up to you, but you need to implement it yourself, as an ISV.

The important piece to differentiate clients, however, is being aware of the TenantId for each user, so you can look up which client's settings you need from the database. The most simple way to do this is simply the `tid` property on the Teams tab context. You can read more about that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/access-teams-context). Unfortunately, because it's just accessed via Javascript, it's not entirely secure - for a more secure mechanism, you should be creating an Azure Application, and generating jwt tokens that you can authenticate against in your backend. It's a much more complex topic, but hopefully this answer at least gives the background you need. For more info on the security aspects (validating the token etc.), please see this question: [How to restrict access to Azure Function to only allow requests from a custom Microsoft Teams App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69962403/how-to-restrict-access-to-azure-function-to-only-allow-requests-from-a-custom-mi).

Comment: Thank you for the response. I understand I can store customer data in "MY" database, but that's not exactly the point of my question. I'd like to know if there is a way to store data in CUSTOMER's environment (please check the part highlighted in bold). An example for user-level settings that could be a file on the user's one drive. But what about tenant level settings?

Comment: oh ok, I see. Why is it critical that the data be stored specifically in the customer's own database? In any case, you could have them provision their own storage, e.g. in Azure, and provide you with credentials (e.g. connection string) that you could store in your own database. Your database wouldn't really hold any -data-, other than the tenant id and the connection string to their own owned database. That might work?

Comment: The question is if there is something out of the box for that. So that I don't need to ask the customer to do anything but just use that. I just would like to store any customer data at not my location, but at customer's location

Comment: No, I don't think there's anything 100% out of the box for that. If you want something really simple/turnkey, you might be able to do something in Dataverse for Teams: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-platform/admin/about-teams-environment

Comment: Thanks, will have a look!

Comment: Nikolay, did you get any further with this?

Comment: Not really, that all looks way too complicated. No use for me. I expected something as simple as local storage.

Comment: Local storage isn't safe because a user can move between devices (e.g. Teams mobile), but other than that it's no more complex than any other backend. Your tab is, after all, just a web application like any other (e.g. SPA), which would have it's own API and data store of some sort.

Comment: Yes, I just put "localstorage" as a clear example of storage with two operations (get/set) and no configuration. The dataverse thing looks to me like a space occupied by aliens. For now, the only option I see seems to be our own backend (which we have, but we wanted to avoid storing user data by us).

Comment: Got you. If the original answer was helpful, please remember to upvote so others can benefit too. Good luck with the project.

Comment: Is saving data as cookie will not help here @Nikolay?

Comment: @HunaidHanfee-MSFT Please note that we are talking about saving data per-organization (tenant). Means, it should be shared between all users of a tenant. When an admin for example modifies it, all users are supposed to get an updated version of that data. I don't see how a cookie can help here.